# Is there a way to create a pattern/tendency in excel/sheet google?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Sometimes my sheet got confused because it does not understand the pattern i want it to follow.

For example, i have in one square:

=(SEN(HD1*(2*PI()*7216.35)*(G2))/HD1)*24.1/515

the square immediately at right is, for example:

=(SEN(HD1*(2*PI()*7216.35)*(G3))/HD1)*24.1/515

IF i select both squares and try to drag it along the horizontal line, i would expect that the sheet understand that HD1 remains constant, and G3 follows the pattern. But it will not understand it.

Is there a way to make the sheet understand what i am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Select the cell references you want to be static and use `F4` to cycle through absolute cell references.

When dragging Excel will do the following:

- "unlocked" cell reference: `G2`
- "column locked" cell reference: `$G2`

  - when dragged horizontally the column will remain the same "G", the row 2 will remain the same. If dragged vertically then the row number "2" will increment to 3 and so on.
- "row locked" cell reference: `G$2`

  - when dragged horizontally the column will increment "G", "H" and so on, the row "2" will remain the same. If dragged vertically then the row will remain the same.
- "row and column locked" otherwise known as absolute: `$G$2`

It sounds like you want your formula (before dragging) to be

```
=(SEN($HD$1*(2*PI()7216.35)(G2))/$HD$1)*24.1/515
```